# Has this topology a name?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition

let $(X,\tau )$ be the topological space where  $\tau =\{\emptyset, X, \{x\}, X-\{x\}\}$ , $ x \in X$.

Does this topology have a name? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, but it is the disjoint union of a one-point space and an [indiscrete space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology) (namely, $\{x\}$ and $X - \{x\}$).

Comment: generally I have $\forall Z \in\tau(X-Z \in \tau) $ Is correct?

Comment: @ГарнакОлэговытц For a topology in general? No, because that says that every open set is closed (i.e., every open set is a union of connected components), which is pretty dang rare. For your space, yes, it's true.

Comment: for my space.. ;) :)